# Align footer section of modal to center

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, slds, modal

I want to display the buttons in the footer section to the center and I'm using the modal container. I have tried multiple CSS but none of them are not working, could you please suggest me the correct approach

My Div:

```
<footer class="slds-modal__footer " >
     <lightning:button type="Cancel" label="Cancel" variant="neutral" onclick="{!c.cancelAction}"/>
     <lightning:button type="Submit" label="Save" variant="brand" />
</footer>
```

[image: Current one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SLDS grid system](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/#Content-centered).
With the `slds-grid` class you define a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) then with `slds-grid_align-center` class you set the alignment of its content.
So you can define a div with these two classes and putting the buttons inside

```
<footer class="slds-modal__footer">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-center">
         <lightning:button type="Cancel" label="Cancel" variant="neutral" onclick="{!c.cancelAction}" />
         <lightning:button type="Submit" label="Save" variant="brand" class="slds-var-m-left_x-small" />
    </div>
</footer> 
``
```

Comment: It's working like a charm. Much appreciated